# How to read from and write to the same EXCEL file using Ruby?

Tags: ruby, excel, spreadsheet, xls

I want to read from and write to the same EXCEL file (file.xls) using Ruby. I tried to use Roo gem which doesn't allow to write to the file. Now I am using Spreadsheet gem, but I can't update existing data in the same excel file.

Is it possible to read from and write to the same EXCEL file without change in macros using Ruby?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a similar post that received an answer: [I want to edit a wellformatted excel file with ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16167075/i-want-to-edit-a-wellformatted-excel-file)

Basically, you may want to check out win32ole: http://davidsulc.com/blog/2011/03/27/using-ruby-and-win32ole-to-manipulate-excel/

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to make Roo read and write from the same file. This could be due to the fact that Roo creates a temporary file before it writes.  Writing to a new file is cleaner, easier and supported.  I have the data that I want to read from in my project under db/data/import, then I write to db/data/export and everything got way easier once I went with this approach.