# I want to edit a wellformatted excel file with ruby

Tags: ruby, excel

I have a wellformatted excel file with a lot of macros and styling in it that I want to keep.
Then i have this information I want to enter in the file.
And I want to do it with ruby.

I've tried roo and spreadsheet but they don't seem able to actually edit the file, just create a new one and loosing all the formattin in the process.

It feels it should be simple to just edit the cells I want and save the file again but obviously it's more complex that I originally though(or I'm completely blind)

Any help is appreciated.

I'm learning ruby at the moment so that's why I would prefer a solution in ruby.
If you know there are better suited laguages for this feel free to point  me in the right direction and I'll check it out.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have a look at `WIN32OLE`. Except some performance issue, it may fit your need.

Comment: thanks! WIN32OLE works nicely for my purposes.

Answer (score 2):

Speaking from experience, there is no Ruby gem that would handle Excel files with all bells, whistles, macros and styling. It is a pity, because Excel is squarely the finest of Microsoft products. In my experience, `spreadsheet` library can import legacy data from Excel, LibreOffice Calc etc. (I'm not sure about Gnumeric).

As for your problem of getting data from Ruby to Excel, I suggest that you first save Ruby output as a separate file (spreadsheet, CSV, text...) and then teach Excel to import it (eg. using macros).

Another possibility is to abandon Excel for data processing tasks (and possibly keep it for data presentation tasks). Excel is great for presentation and simple data processing, but very bad for complex algorithms.

I wrote gems `yzz` and `y_nelson`, which I intended as Ruby replacement for spreadsheets. Yzz provides Ted Nelson's ZZ structures in Ruby (ZZ structure is an improved version of spreadsheet data structure) and `y_nelson` mixes it with Petri nets (because Petri nets are an improved version of Excel cell functions). Mathematically speaking, a spreadsheed is a hybrid between some sort of multidimensional orthogonal grid of data cells plus a Petri net execution engine. With `y_nelson`, I hope to bring dearly missed Excel functionality into Ruby, while at the same time moving one step towards better abstraction.

Comment: THanks for your answer but win32ole does actually what I was asking for. it allows me to make changes on the excel document in question without losing any formating. I realize thou that this has it's limitation as it needs Excel to be installed to work.

Comment: So Excel has now API in Windows. That makes it even better. Back when I did huge amounts of work with Excel, I didn't have this luxury. I generally didn't use macros, I found that recursive formulas and conditional formatting worked really well for me. Back then, Excel was the only piece of software holding me in Windows before I switched to Debian.

Comment: I think there is a somewhat new gem that is better than roo; I think it built upon the older spreadsheet gem, and comes with LOTS of examples. Unfortunately I can't remember the name right now :( but in case someone finds the thread here, it is some active project on github (at the least active in 2020).